# The <svn> type doesn't support the "svnkit" attribute

Tags: svn, build

I am using a build.xml that has been working for sometime. I use ant version apache-ant-1.8.2. Sorry, I am not aware of the SVN version
I have something like this in the `build.xml`:

```
svn javahl="false" svnkit="true" username="user" password="password" failonerror="true"
```

setting svnkit to false did not help either :(

The build fails at this line with this error

```
The <svn> type doesn't support the "svnkit" attribute.
```

Comment: This has been fixed in my system. The ant jar were somehow corrupted. So did a reinstall and it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the documentation of [SVN task at tigris](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html), you will see that the attributes `svnkit` and `javahl` are deprecated after version 1.3.2 of SVNAnt. Perhaps you have a newer version installed. Have you tried to left out the attribute? It is not required.

And please, try to include in your question at least the context of the line, at the moment, it is no valid Ant build file at all (no markup).